# Whitespace character which is not the usual 'space'

Tags: vimrc

I came across this character which looks like the usual space character but it is not identified with the usual highlight search '/' in Vim. For context, I added a space at the very last line to show the searchable space (in yellow highlight) while the space-like characters on other lines which are not highlighted.

[image]

Could anyone advice on what this is and why it is showing as whitespace?

PS: On Vivian's advice I used `ga` on the character and got the following:
[image]

Comment: To get more information about the character it would be good if you could move your cursor on it and type `g8` to know what is behind (`ga` could also give some information)

Comment: Thanks for the edition. This is a classical space :-) How do you search for space (`/` redo the last search but does not tell you what search you do)? What is the result od `/\s`?

Comment: When possible, [please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Comment: If `ga` isn't lying: that is a space. https://bestasciitable.com

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble @Vivian De Smedt, I did not retain the original file thinking I could replicate it but now when I use the forward slash `/` to search it clearly shows up as space. And I am sure it was not a space because I ended up using %s on the original file and searching for copies of that character to search and delete it. I was only curious to know what that is so thank you for sharing the `ga` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyse these special characters I recommend the [unicode](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) plugin. It overrides the `g8` command to give you more information about these special characters.

There are numerous Unicode characters that look like space and are not (here is a [list](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs)).

A typical example is the non breaking space (`U+00A0`).

You can insert it using the key sequence: <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>`u00a0`